# Upload image directly from the desktop in CSS on Formstack

Tags: css, path, formstack

I need to upload an image using CSS. Image is store inside a folder(X) on a desktop. I need to upload this image directly from the desktop

```
.fsBody .fsForm {
    background-image: url('C:\Users\Accountant\Desktop\X\test.jpg');
}
```

Image seems it does not upload directly to my Form. Image is JPEG Format.

Comment: You can't reference a folder structure like that and expect it to work. You have to include the image files in the same folder alongside all your other CSS and HTML files.

Comment: I am using Formstack

Comment: Regardless of what you're using you shouldn't be referencing images like that.

Answer (score 0):

If the image you want to use is going to be set as a background image, put it directly in the folder you are creating your project in. Just move it in there by dragging it inside.

```
.fsBody .fsForm {
background-image: url('folderlocation');
}
```

the issue with the way you are referencing the location is that when you upload your project folder the image will not be in that folder as it will be on a separate location. Therefore it has no way of finding it.